# SQL group by similar address but different longitude and latitude

Tags: sql, postgresql, street-address

I Have a large Postgres dataset table,
the table ('tbl') has 4 columns,
and a data similar to this:

| ID | address | x,y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 E 4th Ave, Cordele, GA, 11015 | x1,y1 |
| 2 | 22 E 4th Ave, Cordele, GA 11015 | x2,y2 |
| 3 | 408 E 5th Ave, Cordele, CA 11215 | x2,y2 |
| 4 | 408 E 5th Ave, Cordele, CA, 11215 | x2,y2 |
| 5 | 408 E 5th Ave, vic, VA, 11215 | x2,y2 |
| 6 | 408 E 5th Ave, vic, VA, 11215 | x3,y3 |

My question is , how to find all the addresses that have similar address (similar address means ignoring the comma between the state and zip, *that's the only part that should be ignored*), But having different 'x,y' value

In the above example , id 1 and 2 should be returned because they have the same address ( with a diff in the comma) But different 'x,y' values.

Id 3 and 4 should not be returned because their 'x,y' values are identical.

Id 5 and 6 should not be returned because their address values are identical.

*I can count on the address format to always have a state and a zip

Answer (score 0):

It might be overkill, but can you just remove *all* commas and compare?

```
select array_agg(distinct address)
from t
group by replace(address, ',', '')
having min(x_y) <> max(x_y);
```

To specifically remove that comma, you could instead use:

```
select array_agg(distinct address)
from t
group by (case when address like '%, _____'
               then left(address, -7) || right(address, 6)
               else address
          end)
having min(x_y) <> max(x_y);
```

Comment: Doesn't the `CASE` expression need `ELSE address`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how many variations you have in your data, but I was able to get what you want on the sample data provided. I inserted the data in a table named locdat, you could change columns and table as per your need.

```
SELECT
    id, address, xy
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            l.*,
            COUNT(l.address)
            OVER(PARTITION BY replace(l.address, ',', ''))             AS addr_count,
            COUNT(l.xy)
            OVER(PARTITION BY replace(l.address, ',', ''), l.xy)       AS xy_count
        FROM
            locdat l
    )
WHERE
    ( addr_count >= 1
      AND xy_count < 2 );
```